# is changes needed in provisiong profile for iads (only for testing purpose)

Tags: iphone, provisioning, iad

i have an application in development stage, i want to add iAd functionality, i follow all steps from apple guidelines for iAD, its working fine on simulator, but when i test it on device, its not showing test advertisement. i want to know that is i have to make another provisioning profile. I didn't change my provisioning profile and using older one.
Is test advertise also needed a iad enabled provisioning profile.
i have another question that is , is test advertise is also available for outside US, i am in south asia, so will it be the reason for not showing test Advertisement.

Please help me, what should i do.